# SELECT Data from Two Separate Tables

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have two separate tables. I need to SELECT the *avatar* from the **user** table, WHERE the username equals *from* on the **comments** table. I am trying to create a comment system that displays the user's avatar next to their message.

**Comments** - ID|Username|From|Timestamp|Message
**User** - ID|Username|Avatar

```
$fetchto=mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$variable'"));
```

I think I could display the URL to the avatar using $fetchto->avatar if I had a variable that would pull the avatar of the member making the comment from the user table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off your database isn't [properly normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). The comments should refer to the `User` by `UserId`, not by `Username`. Once you've fixed that:

```
select * from Comments c
join User u on u.ID = c.UserId
```

Until then:

```
select * from Comments c
join User u on u.UserName = c.UserName
```

Also, please stop using the `mysql_` family of functions - [they're deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs to have a simple join, something like this:

```
SELECT c.*, u.avatar
FROM comments AS c
JOIN user AS u ON c.username = a.username
```